# RAM usage of Google OR-Tools Java API of CP-SAT model

Tags: java, or-tools, heap-dump, cp-sat

I am using the Java bindings for the CP-SAT model in OR-Tools. My application creates a big model but only holds a few refernces to some Int- and BoolVars.
I realized that after the creation of the model (even before I call of CpSolver#solve). The Java Heap allocates multiple gigabytes just for the model.

I made a heap dump and found following entries:

```
 long []   (mostly part of IntegerVariableProto$Builder, > 13,000,000 inst.) => 1,433 MB
 com.google.ortools.sat.ConstraintProto$Builder (> 8,000,000 instances)      => 1,194 MB
 com.google.protobuf.SingleFieldBuilderV3       (> 21,000,000 instances)     =>   682 MB
 com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$1       (> 21,000,000 instances)     =>   511 MB
 com.google.protobuf.IntArrayList               (> 13,000,000 instances)     =>   445 MB
 com.google.protobuf.LongArrayList              (> 13,000,000 instances)     =>   433 MB
 ...
```

I understand, that a big model needs some memory.
But after I had a look in the Java bindings code, it seems to me that theses objects are only used by protobuf to build a message to send the information to the native backend.

My question is:

Is there any way to use the Java API, without keeping these objects in memory (e.g. by incrementally flushing the model) and still having a reference to CpModel and some variables?

And how would it behave when I use C++ instead?
I am confused here because

- I found an answer in the google group, it says that in C++ the model does not need to be serialized (https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/5-6OthD5JQo/m/ZzeeXD34AAAJ)
- I had then a look in the repository (https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/stable/ortools/sat) and saw that protobuf seems to be used there.

I tried it with OR-Tools version 9.3 and 9.7.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the java wrapper is quite light. An intVar uses 2 pointers and one int32. Not much to gain here, and not much that can be deleted.

When solving, it will serialize the model to string, cross the C++/Java layer, rebuild the proto in C++, then solve using the C++ code.

Doing it in C++ will remove one copy and one serialization.

You have a bigger issue IMO with solve.
Last time I checked, solving a 12M variables problems with a healthy number of workers took more than 256GB of RAM.

So it would be better to decompose the model, try to solve it sequentially, try to reduce its size. This would be time better spent than optimizing the intermediate layers.

Comment: I aggree that IntVar is not the problem here. 
Actually IntVar objects are garbage collected when I do not have any reference to them. 

But for some reason there are lot of protobuf related objects in memory (SingleFieldBuilderV3, GeneratedMessageV3, IntegerVariableProto$Builder ...)
They are not garbage collected. 

I just thought there is maybe a way to serialize variables and constraints in the moment there are created. So that there is no need to keep the protobuf objects in memory. 
But to be honest, I do not know much about protobuf.

Comment: About solving: You are right I think. But also with a smaller model I would like to avoid to pay the memory for the protobuf objects.

Comment: I consider using C++. 
I think about writing the model from Java to a file in a custom format. 
Then I can write a small C++ library that reads the file and builds the model on native side.

You wrote 
`Doing it in C++ will remove one copy and one serialization.`

So is it right that objects like SingleFiledBuilder or GeneratedMessage doe not appear on C++ side. 
I just ask because I saw int cp_model.h the class IntVar and there is the comment 
`This class wraps an IntegerVariableProto.`

This makes me worry that I will have the same problem doing it in C++.

Comment: The wrapping is the same. An IntVar is a pointer to the cp_model proto and an index. And this wrapping is not build when solving from java. Still, the C++ allocation is leaner.